# On Android, does the DefaultHttpClient properly cleanup the HttpPost when an exception is thrown?

Tags: android, exception, httpclient, http-post

I am seeing a problem with reusing my http-client after an HttpPost's execute fails.  It can be a timeout or service not available (maybe others).  The request might throw a socket-timeout and when i later use the client (with a new HttpPost object) it will throw an illegal state exception.  My research indicates that this occurs when the socket is not marked for "reuse" as in the case that naturally occurs if you have two threads and one is in the middle of processing its request before the second thread tries to use the http-client (hence its socket).

I think there is a bug in the http-client code, but there could be either some 'best practises' that I am not following correctly or some known work around.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My research indicates that this occurs when the socket is not marked for "reuse" as in the case that naturally occurs if you have two threads and one is in the middle of processing its request before the second thread tries to use the http-client (hence its socket).

HttpClient is not thread-safe by default. You need to use a [`ThreadSafeClientConnManager`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java).

Comment: OK, i will the thread safe client connection manager - but if i am serialized (i.e., through a work queue) then it should work safely.  But what about the question of an exception followed by another request.

Comment: i just added the ThreadSafeClientConnManager, but i have another question (post separately??) when is a good time in the application life-cycle to call httpClient. getConnectionManager(). shutdown()?  I am using it in an IntentService.

Comment: @mobibob: "But what about the question of an exception followed by another request." I suppose that would depend a bit on the nature of the exception. You might consider asking questions like that on an HttpClient mailing list, since I do not know how much HttpClient support is done here on StackOverflow. " when is a good time in the application life-cycle to call httpClient. getConnectionManager(). shutdown()? I am using it in an IntentService." -- probably `onDestroy()`, if you create the `HttpClient` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks - i will followup on the mailing list.